# vim syntax highlight improve performance

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vi

How do I improve performance when I'm scrolling my files and coding them? With syntax highlighting, vim is so slow. When I switch it off, everything is ok. 
Is there a way or any recommendations to make it faster?

Comment: Edit smaller files?  What vim filetype is selected?

Comment: My syntax highlighting is fine. Which version of Vim are you using? Normal text/console mode or gVim? Which operating system? Running vim locally or remote? Who created the syntax rules file? How fast is "so slow" - can you quantify the speed?

Comment: I have the same problem with C syntax highlight and foldmethod=syntax.

Comment: The colorscheme might make a difference too. Try a number of them.

Comment: Im using php syntax highlight file from vim distro. php.vim and sometimes when alot of functions on the screen, it freeze when scrolling. i use gVim on my ubuntu

Comment: The cause of slow vim files most of the time is long lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901313/editing-xml-files-with-long-lines-is-really-slow-in-vim-what-can-i-do-to-fix-th

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try these settings:

```
set nocursorcolumn
set nocursorline
set norelativenumber
syntax sync minlines=256
```

Also check http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting

Comment: thanks, i will try, but now i have intel i7 sandy bridge core, and don't see any freezes =)

Comment: Thanks for the 'nocursorline' tip. I've suffered from gvim being somewhat sluggish for a long time, and disabling cursorline made a considerable difference

Comment: I don't know what `syntax sync minlines` means exactly, but it worked wonders for large PHP that I edit. Thanks!

Comment: It is insane that `cursorline` makes such a huge difference. I brought my vimrc to my raspberry pi, and `nocursorline` basically gave me a speed boost of between 500% and 1000% immediately. No joke. `top` confirms: 95+% CPU (and very delayed) drops to ~20%, just `j` and `k` moving up and down. Editing a large file basically went from impossible to moderately sluggish. I have a 1000+ line vimrc. +1

Answer (score 7):

I was having an issue with slow performance from vim when editing certain CSS files.

I discovered that the cause in my case was large inline images using data urls.

To speed things up, I just modified my .vimrc like so:

```
set synmaxcol=200
```

This did the trick for me.  Hope it helps someone else.  Hat tip to  https://superuser.com/questions/302186/vim-scrolls-very-slow-when-a-line-is-to-long

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `scrolljump`option. The scrolling won't be smoother but rather than scrolling line by line, it will scroll of `scrolljump` lines at once.

You can try :
`set scrolljump=5`

It does not solve your root issue, but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

For large files vim will read the whole file in order to determine the context for accurate syntax highlighting.

Setting a maximum number of lines to scan will greatly increase performance, at the potential cost of accurate syntax highlighting.

Add the following to your .vimrc

```
autocmd BufEnter * :syn sync maxlines=500
```

This will set the maximum syntax buffer size to 500 lines.